# Hive SQL CalcitePlanner: CBO failed due to missing column stats

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

What is the impact of below error in hive and how to avoid it:

> 17/09/14 16:24:25 [main]: ERROR calcite.RelOptHiveTable: No Stats for
>   user@table, Columns: xyz column 17/09/14 16:24:25 [main]: ERROR
>   parse.CalcitePlanner: CBO failed due to missing column stats (see
>   previous errors), skipping CBO

**SQL query-**

```
create table extractdataset
as select id,value, sum(rtne) as rtne_sum
from ( inner query )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run:

```
 analyze table extractdataset compute statistics;
 analyze table extractdataset compute statistics for columns;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: doesn't work, what if this is happening for temporary tables? that's exactly the scenario I am facing.